# Может ли быть TTY без Bash. Как происходит взаимодействие с ядром?

Tags: linux, bash, ос

Решил разобраться, как в Linux происходит взаимодействие с самой ОС, не считая syscall'ы. В моем представлении, у нас есть ttys, к которым подключаются псевдотерминалы, драйвера которых реализуют GUI или эмуляторы терминалов, но я не могу понять, почему bash - является отдельной программой, без интерпритатора команд это же все не имеет смысла. Ну да, мы можем послать что-то допустим через эмулятор терминала, он передаст это в tty, но tty с этим ничего сделать не сможет, ведь взаимодействие с ядром построено по средствам syscall'ов. Или я что-то не понимаю, но я же не могу запустить еще один tty без интерпретатора команд(bash или не bash)

Comment: Но ведь вместо интерпретатора команд можно запустить любую другую программу например

Comment: `$ sudo lsof /dev/tty*` — и ни одной программы *bash*

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Кто-то же обработал команду sudo и lsof. Если это не bash, то кто? В моем понимании у нас есть допустим виртуальный терминал, который присоединяется к tty, драйвер которого кто-то реализовывает, в случае с командами терминала - это какой-то интерпритатор, либо я чего-то не понимаю, взаимодействие с ядром же происходит через syscall'ы, т.е. через обертки Си-библиотеки, интерпритатор их и вызывает, других возможностей взаимодействия - нет, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: Почитайте [для начала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTY-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) / А также `man 4 tty`, `man 7 pty` и SEE ALSO в них

Comment: вывод команды посмотрите. увидите там что-нибудь типа `*getty`, `xorg` (может, ещё что-то). если ни на одном псевдотерминале не залогинились, то ничего похожего на программу *bash* не будет. ну а если залогинились, то увидите в выводе программу *login*. именно её запустит программа *agetty* (или её аналог). и именно она (после удачного логина) запустит программу *bash* (ну или ту, что у вас определена как оболочка по умолчанию). вы, пожалуйста, сформулируйте в тексте вопроса, что именно вам не понятно (и уберите, пожалуйста, из текста лишнюю «воду»).

Comment: *`"драйвер которого кто-то реализовывает, в случае с командами терминала - это какой-то интерпритатор"`* -- если вы считаете, что в драйвер tty зашито распознавание и обработка команд, которые вы вводите с клавиатуры, то вы кардинально ошибаетесь. Ни о чем подобном драйвер tty не знает. Вся обработка вводимых с клавиатуры команд происходит в `bash`

Comment: Вот еще можно [почитать](https://habr.com/ru/company/neobit/blog/330764/)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Я бы с радостью убрал, просто эта "вода" - это то, как  я понимал взаимодействие пользователя с осью.

Comment: @avp т.е. tty - это просто способ донести информацию от input устройств до процесса? И никакой сложной логики он не делает. И создание своего эмулятора терминала - это просто реализация чтения и записи tty(pts)?

Comment: @kaylil_01 В unix вообще стараются делать так что бы никакая программа не обладала сложной логикой. Ибо unix way "Программа должна делать что то одно, но делать это хорошо". Это обеспечивает модульность, по сути конструктор лего из которого собирается все, что угодно. Совершенно не обязательно что после подключения пользователь должен увидеть интерпретатор команд. У нас например была система ввода данных написанная на C, когда оператор заходил в систему то у него была только эта система, в которой он работал, никаких команд интерпретатора он в принципе вводить не мог и ему это было не нужно

Comment: @kaylil_01, в принципе, да, это простой serial (последовательный) интерфейс. Для создания своего эмулятора можете посмотреть на [forkpty](https://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty)

Comment: https://github.com/alex-eri/jsterm вот ещё пример создания терминала. там можно любую программу запустить без баша

Comment: @avp Я написал ответ, но не уверен в том, что он полностью корректен, не могли бы прокомментировать, или лучше, написать свой, я бы отметил, думаю многим было бы полезно, а комментарии, насколько я знаю, не индексируются.

Comment: Говоря о tty почти всегда забывают про [readline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html). А между прочим, это самая распространенная и самая используемая подсистема. Readline есть на всех известных операционных системах. Readline есть в каждом интерпретаторе, будь то bash, nodejs, php, mysql, python, perl, powershell или даже command.com. Именно Readline отвечает за все горячие клавиши при вводе, а многие специальные контролирующие символы были созданы под эти комбинации клавиш и имеют одноименное название.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TTY — это не способ взаимодействия с ОС, это способ взаимодействия с процессом. Первый запущенный ядром процесс `/sbin/init`, запускающий программу `getty`, которая выполняет чтение конфигурационных файлов `/etc/init/console.conf` и `/etc/init/ttyX.conf` и впоследствии отображает на консоль содержимое файла-приветствия `/etc/issue` и запускает `login`. В последствии уже запускается GUI или то, что указано в конфиге. И TTY тут выступает интерфейсом, который знает, в какой файловый дескриптор будет записываться ввод, а какой-нибудь Bash через TTY-структуру поймет откуда читать этот ввод, и куда писать вывод (или не писать в случае с GUI).

Comment: Не понятно, что имеется в виду под *`"TTY - это не способ взаимодействия с ОС, это способ взаимодействия с процессом"`*. Вообще-то tty это файл, через который процесс взаимодействует с OC. Передача данных (чтение-запись) проводится в зависимости от того, с чем конкретно (физическое устройство или псевдотерминал) связан данный tty. При запуске программы ее файловые дескрипторы 0, 1, 2 (stdin, stdout, stderr) наследуются от порождающего эту программу процесса и могут быть связаны либо с tty (это по умолчанию, когда наследуем login), либо с любым другим файлом (это делают `<`, `>`, `|` в shell)

Comment: @avp я под этим имел в виду цель tty. Способ взаимодействия человека с процессом благодаря механизму записи и чтения в tty.